# soapui API, custom data source and testing more than 1 service in free version

Tags: soapui

have downloaded free version of soapUI, got it to work for a simple web service. but not able to figure out how i can use the free version to specify my own data source.

i did a google search and went thru
1. http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/integrating-with-junit.html
2. http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/the-soapui-object-model.html (cannot post more than 2 links)

but did not find a way to do this. my goal is specify input data from a spreadsheet (open office ods or MS excel/ POI)
and then take the return data from the first webservice call, use java or groovy to send the return data + some of the columns from the spread sheet row to a 2nd web service.

Any help in Java API of the SoapUI tool or another way to do the above?

Answer (score 1):

Free version does not support datasource option. I would recommend you to use Groovy script to read from datasource.

Comment: what does that mean -> even if you have a script made in pro version with a data source you cannot run it in free ? OR that the option does not come up in the UI only?

Comment: Pro version has a datasource component (i.e. you can drag & drop a datasource and combine it with data loop component). But for free version, the 'events' still work and thats where you should drop your groovy code that would read from a datasource (ex. xml file, txt file etc)